# How to create ROWID column in DB2?

Tags: db2

I tried:

```
  CREATE TABLE rowid_type
  (
  col1 ROWID NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS,
  col2 int
  );
```

Error:

> Error: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=GENERATED ALWAYS;col1 ROWID NOT NULL;, DRIVER=4.14.111
>
> SQLState:  42601
>
> ErrorCode: -104

### EDIT

I referred this link- https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.apsg/src/tpc/db2z_specifydirectrowaccess.html?view=embed

It shows:

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE
  (EMP_ROWID   ROWID NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS,
   EMPNO       SMALLINT,
   NAME        CHAR(30),
   SALARY      DECIMAL(7,2),
   WORKDEPT    SMALLINT);
```

### EDIT2

- product name : DB2/LINUXX8664
- version : 10.5.0.5

Comment: I would expect `GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY`.

Comment: Which DB2 are you on? The link that you added is for DB2 for z/OS, the error could be from DB2 LUW

Comment: There are severe caveats that limit the usefulness of the `ROWID` type (mentioned in the documentation).  In particular, since the value can be reassigned on reorg, it's really only useful if you have an indexed unique key to begin with...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[My answer applies to DB2 LUW, the question has been updated and is pointing to DB2 for z/OS now]*

Try something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE rowid_type
(
  col1 int NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  col2 int
);
```

There are a couple more options available like setting start and stop values. See the [DB2 docs on identity columns](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dbobj.doc/doc/c0020108.html) for details.

Comment: I am confused now. Is **ROWID** a type as you are mentioning int as data type?

Comment: Depends on your DB2 version, platform and configuration. Most users have INT or another number type and then generate the identities. Are you on z/OS or LUW or i?

Comment: product name : DB2/LINUXX8664, version : 10.5.0.5

Comment: So you are on DB2 LUW, but the documentation you read or linked is for another product, DB2 for z/OS. I would suggest using the `INT` data type as show in my answer as DB2 LUW does not have the ROWID type.

Comment: I am new to DB2. Sorry for the confusion.